# mongo db aggregation using lookup

Tags: mongodb

This is my fist collection

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "name" : "Note for programming in c by sibananda achari",
    "description" : "Note for programming in c",
    "contributor" : [ 
        {
            "user" : {
                "$ref" : "user",
                "$id" : ObjectId("59aa6d59f1649108dd795dd2"),
                "$db" : "lecturenotes_v2"
            },
            "permission" : 3,
            "accepted" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the second one.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59aa6d59f1649108dd795dd3"),
    "user" : {
        "$ref" : "user",
        "$id" : ObjectId("59aa6d59f1649108dd795dd2"),
        "$db" : "lecturenotes_v2"
    }
}
```

how to do a lookup using user id of second collection as local field with contributor user id as foreign field of first collection.

Comment: `DBRef` is not supported with `$lookup`. Use plain `ObjectId` values instead. `DBRef` is an old concept and really should no longer be used.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already?